# How to validate and get Amazon ARN access permissions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

How can we validate a third party [Amazon Resource Name (ARN)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-arns-and-namespaces.html) and get all applied IAM permissions or validate certain IAM permissions with the [AWS SDK for Java](https://aws.amazon.com/sdkforjava/)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of an option to actively retrieve all [AWS IAM Permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/PermissionsOverview.html) applied to an ARN for [Cross-Account API Access Using IAM Roles](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cross-acct-access.html) (assuming that's what you  are after).

However, you can use the AWS Security Token Service's (STS) [DecodeAuthorizationMessage](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_DecodeAuthorizationMessage.html) API action (resp. the AWS SDK for Java's [`decodeAuthorizationMessage(...)`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/securitytoken/AWSSecurityTokenService.html#decodeAuthorizationMessage%28com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.DecodeAuthorizationMessageRequest%29) method) to get *additional information about the authorization status of a request from an encoded message returned in response to an AWS request*:

> The decoded message includes the following type of information:
>
> - Whether the request was denied due to an explicit deny or due to the absence of an explicit allow. For more information, see [Determining
>     Whether a Request is Allowed or Denied](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/AccessPolicyLanguage_EvaluationLogic.html#policy-eval-denyallow) *in Using IAM*.
> - The principal who made the request.
> - The requested action.
> - The requested resource.
> - The values of condition keys in the context of the user's request.

This should at least allow you to *validate certain permissions* upfront and/or provide better guidance to your users for exceptions on request failures due to lack of permission.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, In the AssumeRoleRequest API there is one method  getPolicy() cant we get the policy from that method and in turn fetch the allowed actions to that policy ?. I tried doing that but getting null in return. Do we need some permissions to get that.

Comment: @UditBhatia - the `AssumeRoleRequest` class (and similar the `AssumeRoleResult` one) are just [Data Transfer Objects (DTOs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object), i.e. artifacts of how the AWS SDK for Java handles the request/response parameters for the underlying [`AssumeRole`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRole.html) API action - consequently `getPolicy()`/`setPolicy()` is just the getter/setter method pair for the (optional) `Policy` request parameter within the `AssumeRoleRequest` DTO that you would pass to the `assumeRole(...)` method in turn.